# Indexing and selecting only found columns in Pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am facing a basic problem while using Pandas Python. For example my Dataframe " a " has following columns q,w,e,r. Now I want to take a subset of a.

```
b=a[[w,e,r,z]]
```

but it will not create a subset, since z is not there in a, Please help how I can take care of this problem that despite of not finding z in "a" dataframe, I want "b" to be created with rest of them w,e, r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that using `isin` method isn't the most efficient way to do it:

```
% timeit a[a.columns[a.columns.isin(['w', 'e', 'r', 'z'])]]
out : 1000 loops, best of 3: 528 µs per loop
```

When you just use a filter:

```
%timeit a[[col for col in ['w','e','r','z'] if col in a.columns]]
out: 1000 loops, best of 3: 431 µs per loop
```

On the other hand, using `isin` automatically reindex your columns like creating a dataframe would:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'q':[1],'w':[2],'e':[3],'r':[4]})    
out:    e   q   r   w
    0   3   1   4   2

a[a.columns[a.columns.isin(['w', 'e', 'r', 'z'])]]
out :   e   r   w
   0    3   4   2

a[[col for col in ['w','e','r','z'] if col in a.columns]]
out:    w   e   r
    0   2   3   4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do manual filtering before indexing:

```
filtered_col = [col for col in [w,e,r,z] if col in a.columns]
b = a[filtered_col]
```

Comment: I think you might have made a mistake. You might want to change your second 'for' to an 'if'.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you could do it with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) approach for `a` columns:

```
mask = a.columns[a.columns.isin([w, e, r, z])]
b = a[mask]
```

**Example:**

```
np.random.seed(632)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns = list('abcd'))

In [56]: df
Out[56]:
          a         b         c         d
0 -0.202506  1.245011  0.628800 -1.787930
1 -1.076415  0.603727 -1.242478  0.430865
2 -1.689979  0.885975 -1.408643  0.545198
3 -1.351751 -0.095847  1.506013  1.454067
4 -1.081069 -0.162412 -0.141595 -1.180774

mask = df.columns[df.columns.isin(['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'])]

In [57]: mask
Out[57]: Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')

In [58]: df[mask]
Out[58]:
          a         b         c
0 -0.202506  1.245011  0.628800
1 -1.076415  0.603727 -1.242478
2 -1.689979  0.885975 -1.408643
3 -1.351751 -0.095847  1.506013
4 -1.081069 -0.162412 -0.141595
```